# NDK and iconv.h dependency

Tags: android-ndk

I'm trying to build a lib with Adroid NDK which depends on iconv.h

This is what I did so far:

I created a project structure like this:

```
<my_prj>/jni
    - Android.mk
    - Application.mk

<my_prj>/jni/zxing
    - all my lib source files requiring iconv.h

<my_prj>/external/libiconv-1.13.1
    - libiconv sources downloaded from here http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
```

Here is my jni/Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libiconv

LOCAL_CFLAGS := \
    -Wno-multichar \
    -D_ANDROID \
    -DLIBDIR="c" \
    -DBUILDING_LIBICONV \
    -DIN_LIBRARY

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ../external/libiconv-1.13.1/lib/iconv.c \
    ../external/libiconv-1.13.1/libcharset/lib/localcharset.c \
    ../external/libiconv-1.13.1/lib/relocatable.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
    ../external/libiconv-1.13.1/include \
    ../external/libiconv-1.13.1/libcharset \
    ../external/libiconv-1.13.1/libcharset/include

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS) 

LOCAL_MODULE    := libzxing
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    zxing/DecodeHints.cpp \
    zxing/ReaderException.cpp \
    ...and many more...

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
    ../external/libiconv-1.13.1/include

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libiconv

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

according to this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/012d679319e4ea6e

So, then I run "./configure && make" from /external/libiconv-1.13.1 in order to generate iconv.h from iconv.h.in

Then I run ndk-build from /jni/zxing

- All my zxing now compiles without a problem.
- /external/libiconv-1.13.1/lib/iconv.h compiles as well
- Whereas /external/libiconv-1.13.1/libcharset/lib/localcharset.c gives me the following error:

  lib/localcharset.c:49:24: error: langinfo.h: No such file or directory

My guess is that I did something wrong while doing ./configure && make on libiconv as the inclusion of "langinfo.h" is conditioned by HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET defined in libiconv-1.13.1/config.h which in turn comes from libiconv-1.13.1/config.h.in...

BTW, if I force HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET to 0, then I have others error while compiling localcharset.c

So, I'm out of ideas :(
Can some one help me please?
Thanks, Luca.

Comment: Can you explain how do you solve "error: langinfo.h: No such file or directory" I am trying compile icu library in android and i have the same problem

Comment: http://danilogiulianelli.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-cross-compile-libiconv-for.html